# python как перенаправить logging.info() в sys.stdout?

Tags: python

Настраиваю логгирование на своем python демоне:

```
import logging, os, sys
so = open('info.log', 'a+')
se = open('error.log', 'a+')
os.dup2(so.fileno(), sys.stdout.fileno())
os.dup2(se.fileno(), sys.stderr.fileno())
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logging.info('info')
logging.error('error')
```

Проблема в том, что сообщение "info" уходит в error.log. Как сделать, чтобы инфо-сообщения уходили в info.log ?

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете создать `handler` с помощью класса `logging.StreamHandler` и добавить его к созданному logger'у:

```
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

stdout_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)

logger.addHandler(stdout_handler)

logger.info('info')
logger.error('error')
```

Comment: тогда logger.info() и logger.error() будут уходить в stdout ? Вариант с разделением logging.error() и logger.info() не очень подходит

Comment: Всё будет уходить в stdout.